# Turing machine that splits a string into 3 equal parts in $O(n\log n)$

Tags: algorithms, complexity-theory, time-complexity, turing-machines

I have the following question: given a string $X^n$, where $n$ is divisible by $3$, how to build a **one-tape** Turing machine with complexity $O(n\log n)$ that splits this string into $3$ equal parts?

I manage to build an $O(n^2)$ machine that performs this task. By the way, all my attempts always result in an $O(n^2)$ machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inspired by [this answer](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/160744/161325), here is an idea for building a Turing machine, which follows these steps:

The problem requires that the input size ($n$) is a multiple of $3$. So, for example, let's use the input $X^{12}.$

1. Every $3$ $X$, do a mark:
   $$XXXXXXXXXXXX$$
   $$XXAXXAXXAXXA$$
   The number of marks will be exactly $\frac{n}{3}.$
2. In the first mark, replace it with $1$ and replace the previous $X$ with $C$ (to delimit the end of the number, as later this will prevent the head from going to the beginning of the tape):
   $$XC1XXAXXAXXA$$
3. Move this number to the next mark character by character until you find the delimiter $C$. After that, add $1$ to the number **in binary** and delimit it by marking $C$:
   $$XCXXX1XXAXXA$$
   $$XCXC10XXAXXA$$
4. Repeat procedure 3 until the last mark:
   $$XCXCXXC11XXA$$
   $$XCXCXXCXC100$$
5. Remove the $C$ marks (this can also be done during steps 3 and 4) and move the found binary number to the beginning, but in reverse:
   $$XXXXXXXXX100$$
   $$001XXXXXX100$$
6. At the end of the tape, move the binary number one symbol to the left and subtract it by $1$. Repeat this step until the number is $0$:
   $$001XXXXXX11X$$
   $$001XXXXX10XX$$
   $$001XXXXX1XXX$$
   $$001XXXX0XXXX$$
   After reaching $0$, remove it and mark the previous position.
   $$001XXXXXTXXX$$
7. Repeat step 6, but at the beginning of the tape:
   $$001XXXXXTXXX$$
   $$X11XXXXXTXXX$$
   $$XX01XXXXTXXX$$
   $$XXX1XXXXTXXX$$
   $$XXXX0XXXTXXX$$
   $$XXXDXXXXTXXX$$
   Why must the digits of the number at the beginning of the tape be in reverse positions?
   Let's assume the following case, where the number is in its standard binary form:
   $$...X100XX...$$
   Moving it to the right:
   $$...XX100X...$$
   Subtracting it:
   $$...XXX11X...$$
   In this case, there was a double movement in the number, this does not occur if the number is inverted.

Regarding complexity, the number in binary increases the number of digits logarithmically. In steps 3, 4, 6 and 7, the number moves in $O(\log n)$ time. The number of iterations is according to the size of the input ($n$), so these steps are performed in $O(n\log n)$ time. As for step 5, the number of digits to be copied is in the order of $\log\frac{n}{3}$, as the entire tape is traversed in each iteration, so this step is also $O(n\log n)$.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a high level idea that, for any positive integer $c$ of choice, splits a string of length $n$ (assume that $n$ is a multiple of $c$ for simplicity) into two parts of length $(c-1)n/c$ and $n/c$ using $O(n \log n)$ time. Two applications of this procedure with $c=3$ and $c=2$ (and some technical care) solve your problem.

The algorithm will be iterative and, between iterations, the contents of the tape will be of the form $\alpha \langle C \rangle \beta$, where $\alpha\beta$ is the input string and $\langle C \rangle$ denotes the encoding of a non-negative integer $C$ written in binary.
The position of the head will be on the first character of $\beta$, if any.
I assume that you can mark the start and end of the encoding of $x$ (for example using new tape symbols). I will use $|C|$ to denote the number of bits used in the binary encoding of $C$ (start and end markings are not counted).
At the beginning you can just prepend $\langle 0 \rangle$ to the initial contents of the tape.

As long as $\beta$ is not empty, let $\beta = x \gamma$ (where $x$ is some input symbol) and do the following:

- If $C \neq 2^{|C|}-1$ (i.e., $C$ is not a sequence of $|C|$ ones):

  - Increment $C$ by $1$ (this will use the same number of bits as $|C|$). The contents of the tape are now $\alpha \langle C+1 \rangle x \gamma$.
- Otherwise ($C = 2^{|C|}-1$):

  - Move all the symbols in $\alpha$ one position to the left, the new tape contents become $\alpha\_\langle C \rangle x\gamma$, where $\_$ denotes a blank symbol.
  - Increment $C$ by $1$. This will use one extra bit, which will fit in the blank symbol. The contents of the tape are now $\alpha \langle C+1 \rangle x \gamma$.
- Perform a right cyclic rotation on $\langle C + 1 \rangle x$ (i.e., transform it in $x \langle C + 1\rangle$). The new  tape contents are $\alpha x \langle C+1 \rangle \gamma$.

When this procedure is over, the tape contents will be of the form $\alpha \langle C \rangle$, where $\alpha$ is exactly the input and $C$ is the number of symbols in $\alpha$. We can now divide $C$ by $c$ and continue as follows.

As long as $C \neq 0$, the tape contents are of the form $\alpha  \langle C \rangle \beta$, where $\alpha = \delta x$, for some input symbol $\delta$. Do the following:

- Decrement $C$ by $1$.
- Perform a left cyclic rotation on $x \langle C \rangle$ (i.e., transform it in $\langle C + 1 \rangle x$). The contents of the tape are now $\delta \langle C+1 \rangle x \beta$.

When this procedure stops, the counter $\langle C \rangle$ splits the input string as claimed. You can now delete the counter and, if desired, iteratively shift the right part of the input string to the left until there is a single blank space between the two parts.

To bound the time complexity notice that we perform $O(n)$ iterations in total before $C$ becomes $0$. Each iteration can be implemented in time $O(|C|)  = O(\log n)$, since $0 \le C \le n$. Dividing $C$ by $c$ (which is a parameter of the algorithm), takes time $O(n \log n)$. Deleting $\langle C \rangle$ takes time $O(\log n)$. Shifting the two parts of the string at the end can be done with $O(\log n)$ left shifts of the right part, each of which requires time $O(n)$.

Comment: Thank you so much! Your answer helped me a lot!